# C# How to create a Setup project for a Windows Service to install it automagically?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I have seen multiple Windows Services getting installed in my computer with just an Setup.exe or .msi... is it something special that it needs to be done with the setup project to let such Windows Services installed in a easy way without Installutil.exe?

I have tried and it just doesn't install the Service. I know how to use Installutil but that I would think it's just for testing. I need to be able to install my windows service with an Setup.exe because I want to distribute my Service with its configuration Tray app.

What would be the correct way to install the service and then my app? They both use a same DLL created in the same solution.

[Problem while Building a Setup Project for a windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777401/problem-while-building-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-service)

I looked at the link above but its about the Setup Project which I already know how to do, the problem is how to make my Setup project working... my DLL is getting up in place, the Tray app is working as well, the problem is the Service not getting installed it is just giving me the .exez

but I need it to be installed correctly like be up and running at reboot and in the Service Control Manager.

Comment: A word of advice. Setup Projects have been removed since VS2012. If you want something that will keep on building as you upgrade, abandon Setup Project, and focus on learning to use WiX instead...

Comment: I second that, go with WiX

Comment: Would Wix solve my problem with the Windows Service not getting installed correctly with the setup.exe

Comment: @StevenHernandez "the Service not getting installed how it should" is all we have to go on and is not sufficient information to answer the question above.

Comment: So you are telling me you have successfully installed a service to distribute to end users easily without anything but an install wizard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Option 1**
 1. Download [Wix](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514)
 2. Download and install [Wix Windows Service Setup Project Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7f35c8ce-1763-4340-b720-ab2d359009c5)
 3. Create a new wix setup project and see what you get

This is the easiest way to create a *.msi without any option windows

**Option 2**
Follow this [blog post](http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2013/06/wix-how-to-install-and-start-windows-service.html). Same as option 1 but without the project template. If you go the WiX route sooner or later you will see that the project template provides basic stuff. If you want more advanced stuff you need to learn WiX a little bit and use its candle.exe, light.exe, pyro.exe etc.

**Option 3**
I wrote a [short post](http://outofmemory.azurewebsites.net/windows-service-installer-using-wix/) how I usually do this.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks this solves the visual studio 2012 abandonment of the setup project... But what about my service getting installed? Will that fix tha problem too and install my Windows Service created in my project?

Comment: @StevenHernandez I have several services that I deploy via MSI made with WiX. Yes, it was a massive PITA getting to grips with WiX, but it works very well and appears to be the favoured tool for creating setup files since setupproject was retired. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks that actually helps. Ill test this tomorrow when I get back to work and accept your answer when it successfully work. I appreciate the help.

Comment: +1 - @mynkow Thanks worked perfectly. Only had to instruct myself about how to create the XML. But I do have a problem with my Service maybe you can help me with that of the Project Dependencies how did you fix it? Well my problem was not just the dependencies is says something when installing about not having the privilages to start the service though it is with LocalSystem Account.

Comment: OK, I will write a quick blog post and link it here today.

Comment: @Steven, the error "not having the privilages to start the service" in 99.99% of the times is an error in your service, not permissions. This means that your service is unable to start.

Comment: yeah I figured what the problem was thanks :). It was a silly configuration with how I started my Service since It was the first time actually working after a SetupInstall and without removing the Debugger.

Comment: I wrote a quickpost and sample project how I handle dependencies. Check it: http://outofmemory.azurewebsites.net/windows-service-installer-using-wix/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple template for creating a *.msi installer for a Windows Service with WiX:

http://www.schiffhauer.com/wix-template-for-installing-a-windows-service/

I was able to specify my DLL dependencies with `File` tags.